# JQUERY: Div slider showing sometimes 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Div slider showing sometimes 2 divs or 3, its little bit buggy but I don't know why.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $(function SliderOne() {
        $("#nm_slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#nm_slideshow > div:first').fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#nm_slideshow');
        }, 6500);
    });
});
```

Comment: share all code please

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cause of `appendTo()`. You're appending a new item without removing the previous one. Though, I'd use `.html()` instead, in a way which keeps my animations working.

Comment: Please let me know if this works for you: setInterval(function() {
   $('#nm_slideshow > div:first').hide().next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#nm_slideshow');
  }, 6500);

Comment: This one is another suggestion:

$(function SliderOne() {
  $("#nm_slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
        setInterval(function() {
   $('#nm_slideshow > div:first').fadeOut(1500).next().delay(100).fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#nm_slideshow');
  }, 6500);
    });

Comment: Its showing only sometimes 2 divs when i entered my ( dynamic ) control panel, if i have to stop the slider when i leave the content ?

Comment: You mean how you can stop the slider, sliding? If yes, you'll need a function to stop it. E.g. you can fire your SliderOne() function when you'd like and stop it when you need. It can be handled by an if() or switch() statement or on an event. I know it's not 100% clear but it's why I don't know the whole codes which are effecting the function, including your dynamic panel. But as more description, imagine a toggle. When it's returning true the slider is working and when it's false, the slider stops. So you need another function for the toggle too.